# Do devatas have martial tings ? Do Devatas have semen?

Tags: puranas, bhagavata-purana, shiva-purana, vishnu-purana, brahma-vaivarta-purana

Do devatas like Vishnu Shiva krishna ganapati as sense
Do they have semen

Comment: Yes, in fact Bhagwan Kartikeya, Shasta, etc were produced from Shiva’s semen which has very high potency.

Comment: True, if they take the human or some other purposeful form that needs semen.